# Large error at boudaries while calculating first and second derivative using Finite Difference

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, derivative

I am calculating first and second derivatives of a function a(x,y,z) stored in a 3d array a(n1,n2,n3) using Finite Difference. Here the functional value at boundaries is zero. here is the code in Fortran:

```
implicit none
integer i1,i2,i3

integer, parameter :: n1 = 33
integer, parameter :: n2 = 33
integer, parameter :: n3 = 32

real*8 pi, a(n1,n2,n3), a2(n1,n2,n3), z(n3),x(n1),y(n2),h,a1(n1,n2,n3)
real*8 num(n1,n2,n3),deno(n1,n2,n3),diff(n1,n2,1),A0,dx,dy

pi=3.14159265358979323846d0
dx=2.0d0*pi/(n1-1)
dy=4.0d0*pi/(n2-1)

do i1=1,n1
  x(i1)=-pi+(i1-1)*dx
  do i2=1,n2
    y(i2)=-2.0d0*pi+(i2-1)*dy
    do i3=1,n3
      z(i3)=(i3-1)*2.0d0*pi/n3
      a(i1,i2,1)= dcos(x(i1)/2.0d0) * dcos(y(i2)/4.0d0)  !input array
      a1(i1,i2,1)= - 0.25d0*dcos(x(i1)/2.0d0) * dsin(y(i2)/4.0d0)  !analytical expression of first order y-derivative
    enddo
  enddo
enddo

do i1=1,n1
  do i2=1,n2
    write(20,*)x(i1),y(i2),a(i1,i2,1)
  enddo
enddo
call d1y(n1,n2,n3,a,a2)
do i1=1,n1
  do i2=1,n2
     num(i1,i2,1)=(a2(i1,i2,1)-a1(i1,i2,1))  !numerator of error calculation
     deno(i1,i2,1)=a2(i1,i2,1)               !denomenator of error calculation
     if (dabs(deno(i1,i2,1)) .lt. 1e-10)deno(i1,i2,1)=1.0d0
     diff(i1,i2,1)=dabs(num(i1,i2,1))/dabs(deno(i1,i2,1))  !relative error in 1st order derivative calculation
    write(21,*)x(i1),y(i2),a(i1,i2,1),a2(i1,i2,1),diff(i1,i2,1),a1(i1,i2,1)
    write(21,*)
  enddo
enddo
end

subroutine d1y(n1,n2,n3,a,a2)
implicit none
integer n1, n2, n3, i1, i2, i3
real*8 pi, a(n1,n2,n3), a2(n1,n2,n3), z(n3),x(n1),y(n2),h,a1(n1,n2,n3)
pi=3.14159265358979323846d0
h=4.0d0*pi/(n2-1)

do i1=1,n1
   do i3=1,n3
      do i2=1,n2
         if(i2 .eq. 1)then
            a2(i1,i2,i3)=( -3.0d0*a(i1,i2,i3) + 4.0d0*a(i1,i2+1,i3) - a(i1,i2+2,i3) )/ (2.0d0*h)
          else if(i2 .eq. n2)then
            a2(i1,i2,i3)=( 3.0d0*a(i1,i2,i3) - 4.0d0*a(i1,i2-1,i3) + a(i1,i2-2,i3) )/ (2.0d0*h)
          else
            a2(i1,i2,i3)=( a(i1,i2+1,i3) - a(i1,i2-1,i3) )/ (2.0d0*h)
          endif
       enddo
    enddo
 enddo     
end subroutine
```

My input function `a(i1,i2,1)= dcos(x(i1)/2.0d0) * dcos(y(i2)/4.0d0)`, so the sample input data (for grid no 17*17*16)

```
    -3.1415926535897931       -6.2831853071795862        3.7493994566546440E-033
  -3.1415926535897931       -5.4977871437821380        1.1945836920083898E-017
  -3.1415926535897931       -4.7123889803846897        2.3432602026631496E-017
  -3.1415926535897931       -3.9269908169872414        3.4018865378450254E-017
  -3.1415926535897931       -3.1415926535897931        4.3297802811774670E-017
  -3.1415926535897931       -2.3561944901923448        5.0912829964730140E-017
  -3.1415926535897931       -1.5707963267948966        5.6571305614385013E-017
  -3.1415926535897931      -0.78539816339744828        6.0055777714832775E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        0.0000000000000000        6.1232339957367660E-017
  -3.1415926535897931       0.78539816339744828        6.0055777714832775E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        1.5707963267948966        5.6571305614385013E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        2.3561944901923439        5.0912829964730146E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        3.1415926535897931        4.3297802811774670E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        3.9269908169872423        3.4018865378450242E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        4.7123889803846897        2.3432602026631496E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        5.4977871437821371        1.1945836920083910E-017
  -3.1415926535897931        6.2831853071795862        3.7493994566546440E-033
  -2.7488935718910690       -6.2831853071795862        1.1945836920083898E-017
  -2.7488935718910690       -5.4977871437821380        3.8060233744356645E-002
  -2.7488935718910690       -4.7123889803846897        7.4657834050342639E-002
  -2.7488935718910690       -3.9269908169872414       0.10838637566236967     
  -2.7488935718910690       -3.1415926535897931       0.13794968964147156     
  -2.7488935718910690       -2.3561944901923448       0.16221167441072892     
  -2.7488935718910690       -1.5707963267948966       0.18023995550173702     
  -2.7488935718910690      -0.78539816339744828       0.19134171618254495     
  -2.7488935718910690        0.0000000000000000       0.19509032201612833     
  -2.7488935718910690       0.78539816339744828       0.19134171618254495     
  -2.7488935718910690        1.5707963267948966       0.18023995550173702     
  -2.7488935718910690        2.3561944901923439       0.16221167441072895     
  -2.7488935718910690        3.1415926535897931       0.13794968964147156     
  -2.7488935718910690        3.9269908169872423       0.10838637566236962     
  -2.7488935718910690        4.7123889803846897        7.4657834050342639E-002
  -2.7488935718910690        5.4977871437821371        3.8060233744356686E-002
  -2.7488935718910690        6.2831853071795862        1.1945836920083898E-017
  -2.3561944901923448       -6.2831853071795862        2.3432602026631496E-017
  -2.3561944901923448       -5.4977871437821380        7.4657834050342639E-002
  -2.3561944901923448       -4.7123889803846897       0.14644660940672630     
  -2.3561944901923448       -3.9269908169872414       0.21260752369181418     
  -2.3561944901923448       -3.1415926535897931       0.27059805007309856     
  -2.3561944901923448       -2.3561944901923448       0.31818964514320852     
  -2.3561944901923448       -1.5707963267948966       0.35355339059327384     
  -2.3561944901923448      -0.78539816339744828       0.37533027751786530     
  -2.3561944901923448        0.0000000000000000       0.38268343236508984     
  -2.3561944901923448       0.78539816339744828       0.37533027751786530     
  -2.3561944901923448        1.5707963267948966       0.35355339059327384     
  -2.3561944901923448        2.3561944901923439       0.31818964514320858     
  -2.3561944901923448        3.1415926535897931       0.27059805007309856     
  -2.3561944901923448        3.9269908169872423       0.21260752369181410     
  -2.3561944901923448        4.7123889803846897       0.14644660940672630     
  -2.3561944901923448        5.4977871437821371        7.4657834050342722E-002
  -2.3561944901923448        6.2831853071795862        2.3432602026631496E-017
  -1.9634954084936207       -6.2831853071795862        3.4018865378450254E-017
  -1.9634954084936207       -5.4977871437821380       0.10838637566236967     
  -1.9634954084936207       -4.7123889803846897       0.21260752369181418     
  -1.9634954084936207       -3.9269908169872414       0.30865828381745519     
  -1.9634954084936207       -3.1415926535897931       0.39284747919355117     
  -1.9634954084936207       -2.3561944901923448       0.46193976625564342     
  -1.9634954084936207       -1.5707963267948966       0.51327996715933677     
  -1.9634954084936207      -0.78539816339744828       0.54489510677581865     
  -1.9634954084936207        0.0000000000000000       0.55557023301960229     
  -1.9634954084936207       0.78539816339744828       0.54489510677581865     
  -1.9634954084936207        1.5707963267948966       0.51327996715933677     
  -1.9634954084936207        2.3561944901923439       0.46193976625564348     
  -1.9634954084936207        3.1415926535897931       0.39284747919355117     
  -1.9634954084936207        3.9269908169872423       0.30865828381745508     
  -1.9634954084936207        4.7123889803846897       0.21260752369181418     
  -1.9634954084936207        5.4977871437821371       0.10838637566236978     
  -1.9634954084936207        6.2831853071795862        3.4018865378450254E-017
  -1.5707963267948966       -6.2831853071795862        4.3297802811774670E-017
  -1.5707963267948966       -5.4977871437821380       0.13794968964147156     
  -1.5707963267948966       -4.7123889803846897       0.27059805007309856     
  -1.5707963267948966       -3.9269908169872414       0.39284747919355117     
  -1.5707963267948966       -3.1415926535897931       0.50000000000000011     
  -1.5707963267948966       -2.3561944901923448       0.58793780120967942     
  -1.5707963267948966       -1.5707963267948966       0.65328148243818829     
  -1.5707963267948966      -0.78539816339744828       0.69351992266107376     
  -1.5707963267948966        0.0000000000000000       0.70710678118654757     
  -1.5707963267948966       0.78539816339744828       0.69351992266107376     
  -1.5707963267948966        1.5707963267948966       0.65328148243818829     
  -1.5707963267948966        2.3561944901923439       0.58793780120967942     
  -1.5707963267948966        3.1415926535897931       0.50000000000000011     
  -1.5707963267948966        3.9269908169872423       0.39284747919355101     
  -1.5707963267948966        4.7123889803846897       0.27059805007309856     
  -1.5707963267948966        5.4977871437821371       0.13794968964147170     
  -1.5707963267948966        6.2831853071795862        4.3297802811774670E-017
  -1.1780972450961724       -6.2831853071795862        5.0912829964730140E-017
  -1.1780972450961724       -5.4977871437821380       0.16221167441072892     
  -1.1780972450961724       -4.7123889803846897       0.31818964514320852     
  -1.1780972450961724       -3.9269908169872414       0.46193976625564342     
  -1.1780972450961724       -3.1415926535897931       0.58793780120967942     
  -1.1780972450961724       -2.3561944901923448       0.69134171618254492     
  -1.1780972450961724       -1.5707963267948966       0.76817775671141630     
  -1.1780972450961724      -0.78539816339744828       0.81549315684891710     
  -1.1780972450961724        0.0000000000000000       0.83146961230254524     
  -1.1780972450961724       0.78539816339744828       0.81549315684891710     
  -1.1780972450961724        1.5707963267948966       0.76817775671141630     
  -1.1780972450961724        2.3561944901923439       0.69134171618254503     
  -1.1780972450961724        3.1415926535897931       0.58793780120967942     
  -1.1780972450961724        3.9269908169872423       0.46193976625564326     
  -1.1780972450961724        4.7123889803846897       0.31818964514320852     
  -1.1780972450961724        5.4977871437821371       0.16221167441072909     
  -1.1780972450961724        6.2831853071795862        5.0912829964730140E-017
 -0.78539816339744828       -6.2831853071795862        5.6571305614385013E-017
 -0.78539816339744828       -5.4977871437821380       0.18023995550173702     
 -0.78539816339744828       -4.7123889803846897       0.35355339059327384     
 -0.78539816339744828       -3.9269908169872414       0.51327996715933677     
 -0.78539816339744828       -3.1415926535897931       0.65328148243818829     
 -0.78539816339744828       -2.3561944901923448       0.76817775671141630     
 -0.78539816339744828       -1.5707963267948966       0.85355339059327373     
 -0.78539816339744828      -0.78539816339744828       0.90612744635288778     
 -0.78539816339744828        0.0000000000000000       0.92387953251128674     
 -0.78539816339744828       0.78539816339744828       0.90612744635288778     
 -0.78539816339744828        1.5707963267948966       0.85355339059327373     
 -0.78539816339744828        2.3561944901923439       0.76817775671141642     
 -0.78539816339744828        3.1415926535897931       0.65328148243818829     
 -0.78539816339744828        3.9269908169872423       0.51327996715933655     
 -0.78539816339744828        4.7123889803846897       0.35355339059327384     
 -0.78539816339744828        5.4977871437821371       0.18023995550173721     
 -0.78539816339744828        6.2831853071795862        5.6571305614385013E-017
 -0.39269908169872414       -6.2831853071795862        6.0055777714832775E-017
 -0.39269908169872414       -5.4977871437821380       0.19134171618254495     
 -0.39269908169872414       -4.7123889803846897       0.37533027751786530     
 -0.39269908169872414       -3.9269908169872414       0.54489510677581865     
 -0.39269908169872414       -3.1415926535897931       0.69351992266107376     
 -0.39269908169872414       -2.3561944901923448       0.81549315684891710     
 -0.39269908169872414       -1.5707963267948966       0.90612744635288778     
 -0.39269908169872414      -0.78539816339744828       0.96193976625564337     
 -0.39269908169872414        0.0000000000000000       0.98078528040323043     
 -0.39269908169872414       0.78539816339744828       0.96193976625564337     
 -0.39269908169872414        1.5707963267948966       0.90612744635288778     
 -0.39269908169872414        2.3561944901923439       0.81549315684891721     
 -0.39269908169872414        3.1415926535897931       0.69351992266107376     
 -0.39269908169872414        3.9269908169872423       0.54489510677581843     
 -0.39269908169872414        4.7123889803846897       0.37533027751786530     
 -0.39269908169872414        5.4977871437821371       0.19134171618254514     
 -0.39269908169872414        6.2831853071795862        6.0055777714832775E-017
   0.0000000000000000       -6.2831853071795862        6.1232339957367660E-017
   0.0000000000000000       -5.4977871437821380       0.19509032201612833     
   0.0000000000000000       -4.7123889803846897       0.38268343236508984     
   0.0000000000000000       -3.9269908169872414       0.55557023301960229     
   0.0000000000000000       -3.1415926535897931       0.70710678118654757     
   0.0000000000000000       -2.3561944901923448       0.83146961230254524     
   0.0000000000000000       -1.5707963267948966       0.92387953251128674     
   0.0000000000000000      -0.78539816339744828       0.98078528040323043     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000       0.78539816339744828       0.98078528040323043     
   0.0000000000000000        1.5707963267948966       0.92387953251128674     
   0.0000000000000000        2.3561944901923439       0.83146961230254535     
   0.0000000000000000        3.1415926535897931       0.70710678118654757     
   0.0000000000000000        3.9269908169872423       0.55557023301960207     
   0.0000000000000000        4.7123889803846897       0.38268343236508984     
   0.0000000000000000        5.4977871437821371       0.19509032201612853     
   0.0000000000000000        6.2831853071795862        6.1232339957367660E-017
  0.39269908169872414       -6.2831853071795862        6.0055777714832775E-017
  0.39269908169872414       -5.4977871437821380       0.19134171618254495     
  0.39269908169872414       -4.7123889803846897       0.37533027751786530     
  0.39269908169872414       -3.9269908169872414       0.54489510677581865     
  0.39269908169872414       -3.1415926535897931       0.69351992266107376     
  0.39269908169872414       -2.3561944901923448       0.81549315684891710     
  0.39269908169872414       -1.5707963267948966       0.90612744635288778     
  0.39269908169872414      -0.78539816339744828       0.96193976625564337     
  0.39269908169872414        0.0000000000000000       0.98078528040323043     
  0.39269908169872414       0.78539816339744828       0.96193976625564337     
  0.39269908169872414        1.5707963267948966       0.90612744635288778     
  0.39269908169872414        2.3561944901923439       0.81549315684891721     
  0.39269908169872414        3.1415926535897931       0.69351992266107376     
  0.39269908169872414        3.9269908169872423       0.54489510677581843     
  0.39269908169872414        4.7123889803846897       0.37533027751786530     
  0.39269908169872414        5.4977871437821371       0.19134171618254514     
  0.39269908169872414        6.2831853071795862        6.0055777714832775E-017
  0.78539816339744828       -6.2831853071795862        5.6571305614385013E-017
  0.78539816339744828       -5.4977871437821380       0.18023995550173702     
  0.78539816339744828       -4.7123889803846897       0.35355339059327384     
  0.78539816339744828       -3.9269908169872414       0.51327996715933677     
  0.78539816339744828       -3.1415926535897931       0.65328148243818829     
  0.78539816339744828       -2.3561944901923448       0.76817775671141630     
  0.78539816339744828       -1.5707963267948966       0.85355339059327373     
  0.78539816339744828      -0.78539816339744828       0.90612744635288778     
  0.78539816339744828        0.0000000000000000       0.92387953251128674     
  0.78539816339744828       0.78539816339744828       0.90612744635288778     
  0.78539816339744828        1.5707963267948966       0.85355339059327373     
  0.78539816339744828        2.3561944901923439       0.76817775671141642     
  0.78539816339744828        3.1415926535897931       0.65328148243818829     
  0.78539816339744828        3.9269908169872423       0.51327996715933655     
  0.78539816339744828        4.7123889803846897       0.35355339059327384     
  0.78539816339744828        5.4977871437821371       0.18023995550173721     
  0.78539816339744828        6.2831853071795862        5.6571305614385013E-017
   1.1780972450961720       -6.2831853071795862        5.0912829964730146E-017
   1.1780972450961720       -5.4977871437821380       0.16221167441072895     
   1.1780972450961720       -4.7123889803846897       0.31818964514320858     
   1.1780972450961720       -3.9269908169872414       0.46193976625564348     
   1.1780972450961720       -3.1415926535897931       0.58793780120967942     
   1.1780972450961720       -2.3561944901923448       0.69134171618254503     
   1.1780972450961720       -1.5707963267948966       0.76817775671141642     
   1.1780972450961720      -0.78539816339744828       0.81549315684891721     
   1.1780972450961720        0.0000000000000000       0.83146961230254535     
   1.1780972450961720       0.78539816339744828       0.81549315684891721     
   1.1780972450961720        1.5707963267948966       0.76817775671141642     
   1.1780972450961720        2.3561944901923439       0.69134171618254503     
   1.1780972450961720        3.1415926535897931       0.58793780120967942     
   1.1780972450961720        3.9269908169872423       0.46193976625564331     
   1.1780972450961720        4.7123889803846897       0.31818964514320858     
   1.1780972450961720        5.4977871437821371       0.16221167441072912     
   1.1780972450961720        6.2831853071795862        5.0912829964730146E-017
   1.5707963267948966       -6.2831853071795862        4.3297802811774670E-017
   1.5707963267948966       -5.4977871437821380       0.13794968964147156     
   1.5707963267948966       -4.7123889803846897       0.27059805007309856     
   1.5707963267948966       -3.9269908169872414       0.39284747919355117     
   1.5707963267948966       -3.1415926535897931       0.50000000000000011     
   1.5707963267948966       -2.3561944901923448       0.58793780120967942     
   1.5707963267948966       -1.5707963267948966       0.65328148243818829     
   1.5707963267948966      -0.78539816339744828       0.69351992266107376     
   1.5707963267948966        0.0000000000000000       0.70710678118654757     
   1.5707963267948966       0.78539816339744828       0.69351992266107376     
   1.5707963267948966        1.5707963267948966       0.65328148243818829     
   1.5707963267948966        2.3561944901923439       0.58793780120967942     
   1.5707963267948966        3.1415926535897931       0.50000000000000011     
   1.5707963267948966        3.9269908169872423       0.39284747919355101     
   1.5707963267948966        4.7123889803846897       0.27059805007309856     
   1.5707963267948966        5.4977871437821371       0.13794968964147170     
   1.5707963267948966        6.2831853071795862        4.3297802811774670E-017
   1.9634954084936211       -6.2831853071795862        3.4018865378450242E-017
   1.9634954084936211       -5.4977871437821380       0.10838637566236962     
   1.9634954084936211       -4.7123889803846897       0.21260752369181410     
   1.9634954084936211       -3.9269908169872414       0.30865828381745508     
   1.9634954084936211       -3.1415926535897931       0.39284747919355101     
   1.9634954084936211       -2.3561944901923448       0.46193976625564326     
   1.9634954084936211       -1.5707963267948966       0.51327996715933655     
   1.9634954084936211      -0.78539816339744828       0.54489510677581843     
   1.9634954084936211        0.0000000000000000       0.55557023301960207     
   1.9634954084936211       0.78539816339744828       0.54489510677581843     
   1.9634954084936211        1.5707963267948966       0.51327996715933655     
   1.9634954084936211        2.3561944901923439       0.46193976625564331     
   1.9634954084936211        3.1415926535897931       0.39284747919355101     
   1.9634954084936211        3.9269908169872423       0.30865828381745491     
   1.9634954084936211        4.7123889803846897       0.21260752369181410     
   1.9634954084936211        5.4977871437821371       0.10838637566236972     
   1.9634954084936211        6.2831853071795862        3.4018865378450242E-017
   2.3561944901923448       -6.2831853071795862        2.3432602026631496E-017
   2.3561944901923448       -5.4977871437821380        7.4657834050342639E-002
   2.3561944901923448       -4.7123889803846897       0.14644660940672630     
   2.3561944901923448       -3.9269908169872414       0.21260752369181418     
   2.3561944901923448       -3.1415926535897931       0.27059805007309856     
   2.3561944901923448       -2.3561944901923448       0.31818964514320852     
   2.3561944901923448       -1.5707963267948966       0.35355339059327384     
   2.3561944901923448      -0.78539816339744828       0.37533027751786530     
   2.3561944901923448        0.0000000000000000       0.38268343236508984     
   2.3561944901923448       0.78539816339744828       0.37533027751786530     
   2.3561944901923448        1.5707963267948966       0.35355339059327384     
   2.3561944901923448        2.3561944901923439       0.31818964514320858     
   2.3561944901923448        3.1415926535897931       0.27059805007309856     
   2.3561944901923448        3.9269908169872423       0.21260752369181410     
   2.3561944901923448        4.7123889803846897       0.14644660940672630     
   2.3561944901923448        5.4977871437821371        7.4657834050342722E-002
   2.3561944901923448        6.2831853071795862        2.3432602026631496E-017
   2.7488935718910685       -6.2831853071795862        1.1945836920083910E-017
   2.7488935718910685       -5.4977871437821380        3.8060233744356686E-002
   2.7488935718910685       -4.7123889803846897        7.4657834050342722E-002
   2.7488935718910685       -3.9269908169872414       0.10838637566236978     
   2.7488935718910685       -3.1415926535897931       0.13794968964147170     
   2.7488935718910685       -2.3561944901923448       0.16221167441072909     
   2.7488935718910685       -1.5707963267948966       0.18023995550173721     
   2.7488935718910685      -0.78539816339744828       0.19134171618254514     
   2.7488935718910685        0.0000000000000000       0.19509032201612853     
   2.7488935718910685       0.78539816339744828       0.19134171618254514     
   2.7488935718910685        1.5707963267948966       0.18023995550173721     
   2.7488935718910685        2.3561944901923439       0.16221167441072912     
   2.7488935718910685        3.1415926535897931       0.13794968964147170     
   2.7488935718910685        3.9269908169872423       0.10838637566236972     
   2.7488935718910685        4.7123889803846897        7.4657834050342722E-002
   2.7488935718910685        5.4977871437821371        3.8060233744356721E-002
   2.7488935718910685        6.2831853071795862        1.1945836920083910E-017
   3.1415926535897931       -6.2831853071795862        3.7493994566546440E-033
   3.1415926535897931       -5.4977871437821380        1.1945836920083898E-017
   3.1415926535897931       -4.7123889803846897        2.3432602026631496E-017
   3.1415926535897931       -3.9269908169872414        3.4018865378450254E-017
   3.1415926535897931       -3.1415926535897931        4.3297802811774670E-017
   3.1415926535897931       -2.3561944901923448        5.0912829964730140E-017
   3.1415926535897931       -1.5707963267948966        5.6571305614385013E-017
   3.1415926535897931      -0.78539816339744828        6.0055777714832775E-017
   3.1415926535897931        0.0000000000000000        6.1232339957367660E-017
   3.1415926535897931       0.78539816339744828        6.0055777714832775E-017
   3.1415926535897931        1.5707963267948966        5.6571305614385013E-017
   3.1415926535897931        2.3561944901923439        5.0912829964730146E-017
   3.1415926535897931        3.1415926535897931        4.3297802811774670E-017
   3.1415926535897931        3.9269908169872423        3.4018865378450242E-017
   3.1415926535897931        4.7123889803846897        2.3432602026631496E-017
   3.1415926535897931        5.4977871437821371        1.1945836920083910E-017
   3.1415926535897931        6.2831853071795862        3.7493994566546440E-033
```

Input and output functions are as shown in the figure below.
[image: input function:<code>dcos(x(i1)/2.0d0) * dcos(y(i2)/4.0d0)</code>][image: output:y-double derivative of input function]
As the output function is the same as `- 0.25d0*dcos(x(i1)/2.0d0) * dsin(y(i2)/4.0d0)`, this shows derivative calculation is correct.  Here in subroutine 'd1y', I have used forward and backward finite difference formula for calculation of derivative at boundaries and the central difference for points lying between two boundaries. Then I have calculated the relative error.  I got an error of 0.003 at the boundary of y axis and 0.0015 at the points in between boundaries as shown in fig below[image: view from y axis].

I calculated 2nd derivative using same technique. The subroutine is given below:

```
`subroutine d2y(n1,n2,n3,a,a2)
    implicit none
    integer n1, n2, n3, i1, i2, i3
    real*8 pi, a(n1,n2,n3), a2(n1,n2,n3), z(n3),x(n1),y(n2),h
    pi=3.14159265358979323846d0
    h=4.0d0*pi/(n2-1)
    a2=0.0d0
    i3 =1
      do i1=1,n1
        do i2=1,n2
          if(i2 == 1)then
             a2(i1,i2,i3)=( 2.0d0*a(i1,i2,i3) - 5.0d0*a(i1,i2+1,i3) + 4.0d0*a(i1,i2+2,i3) - a(i1,i2+3,i3))/(h*h)
          else if( i2 == n2)then
             a2(i1,i2,i3)=( 2.0d0*a(i1,i2,i3) - 5.0d0*a(i1,i2-1,i3) + 4.0d0*a(i1,i2-2,i3) - a(i1,i2-3,i3))/(h*h)
          else
             a2(i1,i2,i3)= ( a(i1,i2+1,i3) - 2.0d0*a(i1,i2,i3) + a(i1,i2-1,i3) )/(h*h)
          endif
        enddo
      enddo
   ! enddo 

    end subroutine
```

Here also the error is large at boundaries, in fact, the error is very large compared to first order derivative as shown in figure:[image: view of yz-plane].
Why this large error in boundary? Please explain.

`

Comment: Not sure if related, but in the first snippet you seem to be printing `a(i1,i2,2)` 
before it is assigned any value, in 
this line: `write(20,*)x(i1),y(i2),a(i1,i2,2)`

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and check [ask]. Could you please add a sample of input data you used for your graphs and provide a [mcve], in order for us to be able to help you more effectively?

Comment: comment to your 1st question @RodrigoRodrigues, yes it should be a(i1,i2,1). I am using only one index as my input function is z-independent.

Comment: Of course the error is bigger at the boundary. Forward and backward difference are 1st order accurate and central difference is 2nd order accurate. While you cannot use central difference on the boundary, there are 2 nd order formulas for boundaries. Use one of them.

Comment: Hi @DanSp., the formula I have used for the forward and backward difference at the boundary are of 2nd order accuracy. Still, the error is high! If you know any other expression or any reference, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, I have added input data (but for lower grid size).

Comment: It is 1st order accuracy, Dan Sp. is correct. You should check the total global error, that one should be 2nd order because the boundary layer is getting smaller and smaller with grid refinement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I stand corrected. The names 'Forward Difference' and 'Backward Difference' usually refer to the standard 1st order formulas. You do have correct 2nd order, One-sided 1st derivative formulas.

The 2nd order, 1st derivative, Forward difference formula is derived with a Taylor series expression at x+h and at x+2h as follows:

f(x+h) = f(x) + h*f'(x) + h^2*f''(x)/2! + h^3*f'''(x)/3! ....

f(x+2h) = f(x) + 2h*f'(x) + 4h^2*f''(x)/2! + 8h^3*f'''(x)/3! ....

Now, take 4 times the 1st series and subtract the 2nd series and solve for f'(x). Note that the second derivative term disappears.

f'(x) = 3h/2 * f(x) - 2/h *f(x+h) + 1/(2h) * f(x+2h) + 0 - 4h^2*f'''(x)/3!

This is the formula you are using and it is 2nd order accurate. This does not mean that the accuracy is identical to the central difference accuracy, only that the order of the accuracy is the same.

If you look at the derivation of central difference while keeping the error term, you will find that the error term looks like:

-h^2*f'''(x)/6

Did you note that the error term in the forward difference formula has a constant in front of it. In general, the error will always be larger. But that is not what it means to be 2nd order accurate. The order of accuracy tells you how the error changes when you change h.

For example, if you halve h, you should get about 4 times the accuracy. That means in your example above, the central difference error will go from about 0.0015 to about 0.0004 and the boundary error will go from about 0.003 to about 0.0008

Final Takeaway: Your program is correct and your errors are correct!

Comment: Even second order formulas can produce first order local discretization errors at the boundary. And still the global discretization error can be second order, because the relative portion of the boundary region gets smaller with grid refinement.